# Demonstrating equivalency between Runge-Kutta and Simpson's Rule

Tags: definite-integrals, numerical-methods, approximation, runge-kutta-methods, simpsons-rule

I am trying to show that a fourth order Runge-Kutta method is equivalent to Simpson's method for approximating an integral over an interval [a,b]. I've read that it is, but I'm unsure how to demonstrate this. I would appreciate any help in figuring out how to show this equivalency.

Comment: An integral $\int_{a}^{b}f(t)\,dt$ means you are solving the ODE $y'(t) = f(t)$, $y(a) = 0$. Note that $f$ does not depend on $y$, unlike a general ODE. You can write out the Runge-Kutta method you are interested in and see if it matches Simpson's method in this case.

Comment: Ok, that all makes sense to me. How do I see if they match? What might they look like written out/what step size should I choose for the Simpson? I imagine my confusion comes from the methods looking very different when written out

Comment: The step size is unimportant; call it $h$. On a single interval $[t_i, t_i + h]$ they should yield the same result. If they do, then on the full interval $[a, b]$ they also yield the same result since they yield the same result on each subinterval and the result on $[a, b]$ is the sum of the results on each subinterval $[t_i, t_i + h]$. This is only true when you assume $f$ doesn't depend on $y$. If it does, then the Runge-Kutta is reusing it's approximations, and is different than Simpson's method.

Comment: All right, all of this makes intuitive sense to me. The part I am still confused on is how to show that they yield the same result over a single interval. Yes, it makes intuitive sense to me, but how do I show it mathematically?

Comment: Write out the formulas and using that $f$ doesn't depend on $y$, they should match. For example the integration method $\int_{t}^{t + h}f(x)\,dx \approx hf(t)$ matches the Euler's Runge-Kutta method of order 1 since they do the exact same thing on the interval $[t, t + h]$.

Comment: Yes, but the Runge-Kutta formula is merely a recursive thing for finding each mesh point, correct? w_i? And in the fourth order it requires several intermediary calculations too. Is there a way to write it out as one formula so that I can just "match" it to Simpson as you say? Do you have a resource for writing out Runge-Kutta like that?

Comment: Yes, for quadrature all the Runge-Kutta methods reduce to $y_{n+1}=y_n+h\sum b_if(t_n+c_ih)$. Note that your task has it backwards, Runge constructed the "classical" RK4 method starting explicitly from the Simpson rule.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Runge-Kutta method I think you are talking about is
\begin{align}
&k_1 = f(t_n, y_n) \\
&k_2 = f(t_n + h/2, y_n + hk_1/2) \\
&k_3 = f(t_n + h/2, y_n + hk_2/2) \\
&k_4 = f(t_n + h, y_n + hk_3) \\
&y_{n + 1} = y_n + \frac{h}{6}(k_1 + 2k_2 + 2k_3 + k_4).
\end{align}
If the ode is just integration, i.e. $y'(t) = f(t)$, this reduces to
\begin{align}
&k_1 = f(t_n) \\
&k_2 = f(t_n + h/2) \\
&k_3 = f(t_n + h/2) \\
&k_4 = f(t_n + h) \\
&y_{n + 1} = y_n + \frac{h}{6}(k_1 + 2k_2 + 2k_3 + k_4) = y_n + \frac{h}{6}(f(t_n) + 4f(t_n + h/2) + f(t_n + h))
\end{align}
which is identical to the 3 point Simpsons rule.